# How can use mongodb and node js with complicated query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-modules

I want in node js use mongodb.
I can insert,update ,.... in mongo with node. for example i can select with find but i can not Input  the result of one query1 for query2.

[image: Click here to see image]

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all the records from the collection that match the `where` query then loop over to those records to update only those resultant records that have `c=4`:

```
  MyCollectionName.find({a:{$gt: 4}, b:{$gt: 3}}, function findResult(err, findResult) {
    if (err) {
     console.log('Error on find');
     return;
    }
    findResult.forEach(function (result) {
      if(result.c === 4){
        result.c = 5;
        result.save(function saveResult(err, savedResult) {
          if (err) {
            console.log('Error on save');
            return;
          }
          console.log('Updated...');
          return;
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

Where, `MyCollectionName` is the mongoose model for the collection you wish to query.